# pyspark program for nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new to PySpark and I am trying to understand how can we write multiple nested for loop in PySpark, rough high level example below.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
for ( i=0;i<10;i++)
   for ( j=0;j<10;j++)
       for ( k=0;k<10;k++)
          { 
           print "i"."j"."k"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In non distributed setting for-loops are rewritten using `foreach`combinator, but due to Spark nature `map` and `flatMap` are a better choice:

```
from __future__ import print_function
a_loop = lambda x: ((x, y) for y in xrange(10))
print_me = lambda ((x, y), z): print("{0}.{1}.{2}".format(x, y, z)))

(sc.
    parallelize(xrange(10)).
    flatMap(a_loop).
    flatMap(a_loop).
    foreach(print_me)
```

Of using `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
sc.parallelize(product(xrange(10), repeat=3)).foreach(print)
```

Comment: @Ali `print` in `lambda` work's just fine. Tuple parameter unpacking doesn't, but the OP explicitly uses Python 2.