# remove, or speed-up an explicit for loop in PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

As you'll understand after reading the question, I am new to Spark. I am trying to create a new DataFrame with the list of actions per session to eventually call PySparks [FP-Growth function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-frequent-pattern-mining.html)

To clarify what I want, I have:

```
+-----------+---------+
|sessionid  |event_col|
+-----------+---------+
|0          |        1|
|1          |        2|
|1          |        3|
|2          |        1|
|0          |        3|
+-----------+---------+
```

And want:

```
+-----------+---------+
|sessionid  |   events|
+-----------+---------+
|          0|   [1, 3]|
|          1|   [2, 3]|
|          2|      [1]|
+-----------+---------+
```

I prototyped this in plain Python with a Pandas DataFrame to get the list of events.

```
sessions = []
for sess in df.sessionid.unique():
    session = []
    for action in df[df.sessionid == sess]["event_col"]:
        session.append(action)
    sessions.append(session)
```

I've rewritten it in PySpark (2.0), but literally recreated the for loop:

```
def sessionsbuilder(df):
  df = df.select(['sessionid', 'event_col'])
  sessions = []
  for sess in df.select('sessionid').distinct().collect():
      session = []
      for action in df.where(df.sessionid == sess[0][0]).select('event_col').collect():
          session.append(action)
      sessions.append(session)
  return sessions
```

As expected, this is very slow (over 2 hours opposed to 11 seconds in plain python with pandas). I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31513823/pyspark-program-for-nested-loop) about nested for loops in Spark. I'm having a hard time creating this kind of lambdas for my purpose because of the list initiation in the for loop. There is possibly a way to create such a DataFrame without an explicit for loop or a way to do this more efficiently (maybe a udf), because I'm not leveraging the power of Spark this way.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what you are trying to do. I believe you are trying to combine all the `items` for a each unique `id`. Is it correct?
Also in the code snippet: `sess[0][0]` is incorrect I believe. I changed it to: `sess[0]` to make it work.

Comment: I thought "trying to create a new DataFrame with the list of actions per session" was explanatory enough. `sess[0][0]` is to get the string of the sessionid from the Row object (the first slice gives `sessionid = id`, second slice gives the `id`)

Comment: there is not sessionid and event_col in your created dataframe. how did it even compile?

Comment: The `createDataFrame` is from the documentation of the FP-Growth class in Spark, it is to show how I want the data to be eventually. I edited the name of the dataframe to make it not confusing

Comment: can you edit the question for the changes you made then?

Comment: I guess you don't need to collect data for what you are trying to do. A simple flatmap and groupby would do the required job here.
Try this: `result = df.select( col("id"), explode(col("items")).alias("items_flat")).groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(col("items_flat")))
` for the sample data you provided

Comment: Clearly, I did an awful job at explaining my problem, I changed the question to make clear what I have as input and what I want as output. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe looks as

```
+---------+---------+
|sessionid|event_col|
+---------+---------+
|0        |1        |
|1        |2        |
|1        |3        |
|2        |1        |
|0        |3        |
+---------+---------+
```

Then groupBy and aggregation as stated by Lokesh in the comment above should be sufficient to get the output as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy("sessionid").agg(F.collect_list(F.col("event_col")).alias("events")).show(truncate=False)
```

and you should get the desired output

```
+---------+------+
|sessionid|events|
+---------+------+
|0        |[1, 3]|
|1        |[2, 3]|
|2        |[1]   |
+---------+------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: great to hear that @Chielio